# How to optimize pretrained tensorflow CNN model in order to reduce overfitting and improve overall accuracy for fake face detection

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, overfitting-underfitting

```
vgg19_net = VGG19(input_shape = (200,200,3), include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')

model_vgg19 = Sequential()
model_vgg19.add(vgg19_net)

model_vgg19.add(Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'))
model_vgg19.add(BatchNormalization())

model_vgg19.add(Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'))
model_vgg19.add(BatchNormalization()) 

model_vgg19.add(Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'))
model_vgg19.add(BatchNormalization())
model_vgg19.add(MaxPooling2D())

model_vgg19.add(Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'))
model_vgg19.add(BatchNormalization())
model_vgg19.add(MaxPooling2D())

model_vgg19.add(Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'))
model_vgg19.add(BatchNormalization()) 


model_vgg19.add(Flatten())
model_vgg19.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'))
model_vgg19.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model_vgg19.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5), metrics=['accuracy'])
model_vgg19.summary()
```

Above is my python code wherein I am trying to add layers to a pre-trained VGG19 model. I have a dataset of real and fake faces and it's a classification question. I have normalized pixel values (between 0 and 1) for all images and I am using 80% as training data and 20% as validation data. I am currently getting an accuracy of 95-96% on validation but on my test set I am only getting around 91-92% accuracy. I am new to DL and still learning how to pre-process face images and build effective models. Please let me know if you see any abnormalities in my VGG19 implementation. I have used image augmentation as well but it hasn't proven to be useful. Please let me know how I can make this question better since I am new to SO. Also, the dataset is confidential so I cant share that. Sorry!
Are there any pre-processing techniques I can use on my input images to better train my model?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues in your code.
To improve this:-
You Can Add Dropout To Reduce **OverFitting**, You Can Also Try To Use A ResNet Or A EfficientNet Version (Which Are Better At FakeFace Detection Than VGG);
Most Of All, You Can Toy With The HyperParameters; Your LR is pretty low; Try Increasing It..
If U want advanced techniques, you can try Multiple Outputs Or Use Image Segmentation(It is highly unlikely to help increase your accuracy but multiple outputs might).

P.S. I recently worked on a similar dataset and managed to get 98% accuracy on the test set. ( I Used **`EffNetB2`** )

Comment: what would be the ideal location to add dropout? Thanks.

Comment: The ideal location to add dropout would  be after every batch normalization or every alternate one(the choice is yours.)
However, the value of dropout is something you're gonna have to play with